# Is there a way to Plot intersection point in Manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, intersection

I've tried to plot this . But It seemed useless in `MeshFunctions`

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{{r1 Cos[w1 x], 
    r1 Sin[w1 x]}, {r1 Cos[w1 x] + r2 Cos[w2 x], 
    r1 Sin[w1 x] + r2 Sin[w2 x]}}, {x, 0, t}, 
  PlotRange -> 10 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Earth Trajectory", "Moon Trajectory"}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {{r1 Cos[w1 #] - r1 Cos[w1 #] + r2 Cos[w2 #], 
     r1 Sin[w1 #] - r1 Sin[w1 #] + r2 Sin[w2 #] &}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.05], Pink], 
  AxesLabel -> {"Time"}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red}, 
  BaseStyle -> Thick, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Blue, 
    Point[{r1 Cos[w1 t], r1 Sin[w1 t]}], PlotLegends -> {"Earth"}}],
 {{t, 1, "Time"}, 0.01, 10 Pi, 0.01},
 {{w1, 1, "Angular Velocity"}, 0.2, 5, 0.01},
 {{r1, 2, "Radius"}, 0.2, 10, 0.01},
 {{w2, 1, "Moon Angular Velocity"}, 0.2, 5, 0.01},
 {{r2, 2, " Moon Radius"}, 0.2, 10, 0.01}
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections `` as follows:

```
Manipulate[pp = ParametricPlot[{{r1 Cos[Min[w1 x, 2 Pi]], r1 Sin[Min[w1 x, 2 Pi]]}, 
       {r1 Cos[w1 x] + r2 Cos[w2 x], r1 Sin[w1 x] + r2 Sin[w2 x]}}, {x, 0, t}, 
     PlotRange -> 10 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AxesLabel -> {"Time"}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red}, BaseStyle -> Thick]; 
  Legended[Show[pp, Epilog -> {Black, AbsolutePointSize[5], 
      Point@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[pp[[1]]], 
      PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[{r1 Cos[w1 t], r1 Sin[w1 t]}]}], 
   LineLegend[{ColorData[97]@1, Red, Blue},
     {"Earth Trajectory", "Moon Trajectory", "Earth"},
     Joined -> {True, True, False}, LegendMarkers -> {None, None, "Point"}]], 
  {pp, None},
  {{t, 1, "Time"}, 0.01, 10 Pi, 0.01},
  {{w1, 1, "Angular Velocity"}, 0.2, 5, 0.01},
  {{r1, 2, "Radius"}, 0.2, 10, 0.01}, 
  {{w2, 1, "Moon Angular Velocity"}, 0.2, 5, 0.01}, 
  {{r2, 2, " Moon Radius"}, 0.2, 10, 0.01}, 
  TrackedSymbols :> {t, w1, r1, w2, r2}]
```

[image]